# getWifiState always returns disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi

This is my code at the begining of onCreate:

```
   WifiManager wifix = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Log.v("State", String.valueOf(wifix.getWifiState()));
```

I try enabling and disabling wifi before running the app but it always return

> 1

which is the value of the `WIFI_STATE_DISABLED`

the app is complete actually and as it connects to is own wifi device the Idea is to add a functionality to the app to leave the wifi open (if it was open before opening the app) and close it otherwise.

The app has all required permissions (actually a lot more than needed for this code):

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)     getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifi =   connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (wifi.isConnected()) {
     Log.v("State", String.valueOf(wifix.getWifiState()));
}
```